# CSS Transition Issue—Ken Burn Effect

Tags: css

Image displays, but does not transition.

CSS code is displaying on the uploaded page.

I am using EverWeb to build the page.

Below is the code I am attempting. Thanks in advance.

HTML Snippet

```
<div class="image">
<img src="my_image" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image {
width: 100%;
height: 350px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}
.image img {
animation: move 30s ease infinite;
/* Change this to alternate to stop the loop. */
-ms-animation: move 30s ease infinite;
-webkit-animation: move 30s ease infinite;
-0-animation: move 30s ease infinite;
-moz-animation: move 30s ease infinite;
position: fixed;
left: -150px;
top: -150px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
from {
transform: scale(0.9);
-ms-transform: scale(0.9);
/* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
/* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: scale(0.9);
/* Opera */
-moz-transform: scale(0.9);
/* Firefox */
}
to {
transform: scale(1);
-ms-transform: scale(1);
/* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
/* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: scale(1);
/* Opera */
-moz-transform: scale(1);
/* Firefox */
}
}
```

Comment: did you give transition time

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear how this is supposed to look and I'm not sure why you have positioning in there since the image isn't actually changing size...it just *appears* to.

You can't mix vendor prefixes..each type / statement should be self contained to each vendor.

```css
body {
 text-align:center;
 }

.image {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.image img {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: move 5s ease infinite;
  animation: move 5s ease infinite;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center right;
  -ms-transform-origin: center right;
  transform-origin: center right;
  /* adjust for the zoom effect required */
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes move {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" alt="" />
</div>
```

EDIT: based in *extended* dicussion in comments we have this request.

> I need it in a container 350px high and page wide ("fixed" in place at a certain position). Also, I the image requires scaling down to fit the 350px

Accordingly, I do not believe that an actual image in the HTML would be the best option.

A background image with an animation of `background-position` and `background-size` would seem to be the more logical option.

```css
.burns {
  height: 350px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3999/Tilt-Shift_-_Cityscene.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-animation: ken 10s infinite;
          animation: ken 10s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes ken {
  from {
  background-size: 100%;
  }
  to {
  background-size: 120%;
  background-position: right;
  }
}

@keyframes ken {
  from {
  background-size: 100%;
  }
  to {
  background-size: 120%;
  background-position: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="burns"></div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/xwZNrV)

Comment: Thanks Paulie. The image is now showing, but it drifts onto a black page almost full screen. I need it in a container 350px high and page wide ("fixed" in place at a certain position). Also, I the image requires scaling down to fit the 350px. Current image is10000 x 1490 landscape.

Comment: Code uploaded as requested.